# Reconstruct from two layouts to one layout and move all child views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have *two horizontals LinearLayouts* inside *one vertical LinearLayout*

In each *horizontal LinearLayout* there are 2 `DealsTabletButtons`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/deals_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/all_deals_right_active_now"
                    app:d_text="@string/deals"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/view" />

                <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/categories_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/over_500_top_categories"
                    app:d_text="@string/category"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/brands_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/over_2500_popular_brands"
                    app:d_text="@string/brand"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />

                <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_is_empty="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to reconstruct these layouts **programatically** after screen rotation and achieve something like that:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/deals_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/all_deals_right_active_now"
                    app:d_text="@string/deals"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/view" />

            <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/categories_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/over_500_top_categories"
                    app:d_text="@string/category"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />


            <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_icon="@drawable/brands_icon_red"
                    app:d_lower_text="@string/over_2500_popular_brands"
                    app:d_text="@string/brand"
                    app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />

            <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:d_is_empty="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To catch screen rotation I'm using `onConfigurationChanged` inside `Fragment`

Is it possible to gain this result ?

Comment: Do you have any restriction on using a separate layout in a `layout-land` directory? That would make it easier unless you have specific reasons not to do that.

Comment: @nerdyGeek No I can't do `layout-land` folder, because my app uses       `android:configChanges`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, xmls are just instructions how to build the view programatically.

But you don't need to do that, you can just call this inside in the onConfigureChanged:

```
setContentView(R.layout.landlayout)
```

Sou your onConfigChange would look something like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(isLandOrientation()){
        setContentView(R.layout.land);
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.not_land);   
    }
 }
....
}
```

Comment: If I'm correctly understood. I can't do `layout-land folder`, because my app uses `android:configChanges` and this disables `onConfigurationChanged`.

Comment: maybe I named them wrongly, 'land' and 'not-land' both are in the layout folder not in layout-land

Comment: android:configChanges only means that you are going to handle the configuration changes not the system